# Emacs org-mode HTML footnotes

Tags: html, emacs, org-mode, footnotes

I am taking notes using Emacs org-mode and publishing them as HTML to better read them. But footnotes are appearing in a seperate section at the end. I want to view them in sections they are occuring, like org-mode manual.I have something like this for example;

```
This[fn:1] will be a footnote.
...
[fn:1] This is the footnote reference.
```

What should I do to view the references at the end of occuring section rather than at the end of whole document? By the way, footnotes are not linked as well. When I click on one, that does not bring me to note for that particular footnote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is possible yet, but I see that it's on the TODO list for the project. http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.emacs.orgmode/84807

If the org manual does the footnotes that you want, look at the source of the manual, I'm sure it's in org mode.  :)

Comment: It seems so. Org-mode manual looked like it is generated by Emacs org-mode so I tought it should be possible but I could not find any way to do it. I can't seem to embed a drawer-like TOC to every page either. Manual uses some custom web design I guess.

Answer (score 0):

See the `org-footnote-section` variable, namely:

> This can be nil, to place footnotes locally at the end of the current outline node.

Answer (score 0):

To view footnotes at the end of each section, you can use the `org-footnote-section` option in your org-mode file. This option will automatically place footnotes at the end of each section, rather than at the end of the whole document.

To enable this option, you can add the following line to your org-mode file:

```
#+OPTIONS: org-footnote-section:t
```

You can also customize this option in the org-mode customization interface, by going to the "Org" group, then the "Footnotes" subgroup, and checking the "Footnotes at end of section" option.

In addition to enabling the "org-footnote-section" option, you may also need to enable the "org-footnote-auto-label" option, which will automatically create labels for your footnotes. This option can be enabled in the same way as the "org-footnote-section" option, by adding the following line to your org-mode file:

```
#+OPTIONS: org-footnote-auto-label:t
```

Once you have enabled these options, your footnotes should be placed at the end of each section, and should be automatically labeled and linked.

If you are still experiencing issues with footnotes not being linked or placed correctly, you may need to adjust the "org-footnote-define-inline" and "org-footnote-auto-adjust" options. You can find more information about these options in the org-mode manual, or by consulting the org-mode customization interface.